# R, ggplot2: How do I increase space between specific geom_tile bars to group them in pairs?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I am using ggplot and geom_tile to plot several pairs of colour-coded, categorical time series. The plot is looking fine except that I want to increase the space between each pair of data to improve readability. So each two bars from the same session (e.g. session.1.a and session.1.b) should be close as they are now but I want to increase the space between e.g. session.1.b and session.2.a, and between session.2.b and session.3.a. How could I do this? Any help appreciated =]

This is how a simplified plot looks like:
[image]

A simplified dataset looks like this:

```
mydata <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
    dataID  time    value
                     session.1.a    0   g
                     session.1.a    1   a
                     session.1.a    2   g
                     session.1.a    3   i
                     session.1.a    4   g
                     session.1.a    5   g
                     session.1.a    6   i
                     session.1.a    7   a
                     session.1.a    8   g
                     session.1.a    9   a
                     session.1.a    10  a
                     session.1.a    11  a
                     session.1.a    12  a
                     session.1.a    13  g
                     session.1.a    14  g
                     session.1.a    15  a
                     session.1.a    16  a
                     session.1.a    17  a
                     session.1.a    18  a
                     session.1.a    19  g
                     session.1.a    20  g
                     session.1.a    21  a
                     session.1.a    22  g
                     session.1.a    23  a
                     session.1.a    24  a
                     session.1.a    25  a
                     session.1.a    26  a
                     session.1.a    27  a
                     session.1.a    28  a
                     session.1.a    29  a
                     session.1.a    30  a
                     session.1.a    31  a
                     session.1.a    32  a
                     session.1.a    33  a
                     session.1.a    34  a
                     session.1.b    0   b
                     session.1.b    1   b
                     session.1.b    2   b
                     session.1.b    3   j
                     session.1.b    4   j
                     session.1.b    5   j
                     session.1.b    6   j
                     session.1.b    7   b
                     session.1.b    8   h
                     session.1.b    9   h
                     session.1.b    10  b
                     session.1.b    11  b
                     session.1.b    12  b
                     session.1.b    13  b
                     session.1.b    14  h
                     session.1.b    15  b
                     session.1.b    16  b
                     session.1.b    17  b
                     session.1.b    18  b
                     session.1.b    19  b
                     session.1.b    20  h
                     session.1.b    21  b
                     session.1.b    22  h
                     session.1.b    23  b
                     session.1.b    24  b
                     session.1.b    25  b
                     session.1.b    26  b
                     session.1.b    27  b
                     session.1.b    28  b
                     session.1.b    29  b
                     session.1.b    30  b
                     session.1.b    31  b
                     session.1.b    32  b
                     session.1.b    33  b
                     session.1.b    34  b
                     session.2.a    0   a
                     session.2.a    1   a
                     session.2.a    2   g
                     session.2.a    3   g
                     session.2.a    4   g
                     session.2.a    5   a
                     session.2.a    6   g
                     session.2.a    7   a
                     session.2.a    8   a
                     session.2.a    9   a
                     session.2.a    10  a
                     session.2.a    11  a
                     session.2.a    12  a
                     session.2.a    13  a
                     session.2.a    14  a
                     session.2.a    15  g
                     session.2.a    16  a
                     session.2.a    17  a
                     session.2.a    18  a
                     session.2.a    19  a
                     session.2.a    20  g
                     session.2.a    21  a
                     session.2.a    22  a
                     session.2.a    23  a
                     session.2.a    24  a
                     session.2.a    25  a
                     session.2.b    0   j
                     session.2.b    1   b
                     session.2.b    2   j
                     session.2.b    3   h
                     session.2.b    4   h
                     session.2.b    5   h
                     session.2.b    6   h
                     session.2.b    7   NA
                     session.2.b    8   b
                     session.2.b    9   b
                     session.2.b    10  b
                     session.2.b    11  b
                     session.2.b    12  b
                     session.2.b    13  b
                     session.2.b    14  b
                     session.2.b    15  b
                     session.2.b    16  b
                     session.2.b    17  b
                     session.2.b    18  b
                     session.2.b    19  b
                     session.2.b    20  h
                     session.2.b    21  b
                     session.2.b    22  b
                     session.2.b    23  b
                     session.2.b    24  b
                     session.2.b    25  b
                     session.3.a    0   i
                     session.3.a    1   a
                     session.3.a    2   a
                     session.3.a    3   a
                     session.3.a    4   a
                     session.3.a    5   g
                     session.3.a    6   a
                     session.3.a    7   a
                     session.3.a    8   a
                     session.3.a    9   a
                     session.3.a    10  a
                     session.3.a    11  a
                     session.3.a    12  a
                     session.3.a    13  a
                     session.3.a    14  a
                     session.3.a    15  i
                     session.3.a    16  i
                     session.3.a    17  g
                     session.3.a    18  g
                     session.3.a    19  g
                     session.3.a    20  g
                     session.3.a    21  a
                     session.3.a    22  a
                     session.3.a    23  a
                     session.3.a    24  a
                     session.3.a    25  g
                     session.3.a    26  a
                     session.3.a    27  a
                     session.3.a    28  a
                     session.3.a    29  a
                     session.3.a    30  a
                     session.3.a    31  a
                     session.3.a    32  g
                     session.3.a    33  g
                     session.3.a    34  a
                     session.3.a    35  a
                     session.3.a    36  a
                     session.3.a    37  a
                     session.3.a    38  g
                     session.3.a    39  a
                     session.3.a    40  a
                     session.3.a    41  a
                     session.3.b    0   j
                     session.3.b    1   b
                     session.3.b    2   b
                     session.3.b    3   b
                     session.3.b    4   j
                     session.3.b    5   h
                     session.3.b    6   b
                     session.3.b    7   b
                     session.3.b    8   b
                     session.3.b    9   b
                     session.3.b    10  b
                     session.3.b    11  b
                     session.3.b    12  b
                     session.3.b    13  b
                     session.3.b    14  b
                     session.3.b    15  b
                     session.3.b    16  b
                     session.3.b    17  b
                     session.3.b    18  b
                     session.3.b    19  h
                     session.3.b    20  h
                     session.3.b    21  b
                     session.3.b    22  b
                     session.3.b    23  b
                     session.3.b    24  h
                     session.3.b    25  b
                     session.3.b    26  b
                     session.3.b    27  b
                     session.3.b    28  b
                     session.3.b    29  b
                     session.3.b    30  b
                     session.3.b    31  b
                     session.3.b    32  b
                     session.3.b    33  h
                     session.3.b    34  b
                     session.3.b    35  b
                     session.3.b    36  b
                     session.3.b    37  b
                     session.3.b    38  b
                     session.3.b    39  b
                     session.3.b    40  b
                     session.3.b    41  b
                     ")

desiredLevels=c("a",
                "b",
                "c",
                "d",
                "e",
                "f",
                "g",
                "h",
                "i",
                "j",
                "NA")

desiredLabels=c("a",
                "b",
                "c",
                "d",
                "e",
                "f",
                "g",
                "h",
                "i",
                "j",
                "NA")

mydata$value = factor(mydata$value, levels = desiredLevels, labels = desiredLabels)
```

The code generating the plot is this:

```
  desiredBreaks=c("a",
                  "b",
                  "c",
                  "d",
                  "e",
                  "f",
                  "g",
                  "h",
                  "i",
                  "j",
                  "NA")

desiredColours = c("#009E73", 
                   "#009E73", 
                   "#F0E442", 
                   "#F0E442", 
                   "#CC79A7", 
                   "#CC79A7", 
                   "#D55E00", 
                   "#D55E00", 
                   "#56B4E9", 
                   "#56B4E9", 
                   "white")

ts.plot = ggplot(mydata, aes(x = time, y = dataID, fill = value))  
ts.plot = ts.plot + geom_tile(stat="identity", width=1, height=.9)
ts.plot = ts.plot + scale_fill_manual(drop = FALSE, 
                                      name = "categories",
                                      breaks = desiredBreaks, 
                                      values = desiredColours)


time.labels = c(0, rep("",4), 5,rep("",4), 10, rep("",4), 15,rep("",4), 20, 
                rep("",4), 25,rep("",4), 30,rep("",4), 35,rep("",4), 40, rep("",4), 45)
time.breaks = seq(from=0,to = 45,1)


ts.plot = ts.plot + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-1, 45), expand = c(0,1), breaks = time.breaks, labels = time.labels)

ts.plot = ts.plot +  labs(title = "main title", 
                          x = "\ntime (s)",
                          y = "") 

ts.plot = ts.plot +  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(2)),         
                           axis.text.x = element_text(size  = 24, colour = "black"),
                           axis.text.y = element_text(size  = 24, colour="black"),
                           axis.title.x = element_text(size  = 24),
                           legend.text = element_text(size  = 24),
                           legend.direction = "vertical",
                           legend.position = "right",
                           legend.key=element_rect(size=1, colour = "black"),
                           legend.key.size = unit(1, "lines"),
                           legend.title = element_text(size  = 24),
                           axis.ticks.y = element_line(size=2),
                           panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 

ts.plot = ts.plot + guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=1), title.position="top" )

ts.plot
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also try facets:

```
mydata$group = gsub("session.", "", as.character(mydata$dataID))
mydata$group = gsub("\\..", "", mydata$group)
mydata$group = paste0("Session ", mydata$group)
mydata$group = factor(mydata$group)

mydata$dataID = gsub("\\.[1|2|3]", "", as.character(mydata$dataID))
mydata$dataID = gsub("session.", "", as.character(mydata$dataID))

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = time, y = dataID, fill = value)) + 
   geom_tile(stat="identity", width=1, height=.9) + 
   facet_grid(group~.)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
labels <- levels(mydata$dataID)
# the numbers in the first vector here define the positions/distances of the tiles:
mydata$aux <- rep(c(1,2,4,5,7,8), times = table(mydata$dataID))


ts.plot = ggplot(mydata, aes(x = time, y = aux, fill = value))  
ts.plot = ts.plot + geom_tile(stat="identity", width=1, height=.9) + scale_y_discrete(breaks = c(1,2,4,5,7,8), labels = labels, limits = c(1,2,4,5,7,8))
ts.plot
```

[image]